# Is there any way to sync installed software between two devices?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, sync

The software center in Ubuntu 12.04 had an option to sync software between computers with Ubuntu One (see [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/111989/how-to-sync-quickly-reinstall-applications-on-ubuntu/)).

Is there any way to achieve this in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: You mean, you want to install the same set of software in both devices, and want them to be automatically sync, so that when you install a new software in one computer, it gets automatically installed in the other computer?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/q/1300478/124466) your question and clearly mention what you want to achieve.

Comment: yeah, that is exactly what I want

Comment: While I don't know how to "sync" software between two computers, you can create custom installer image of Ubuntu containing all your customized software, and then install that custom version of Ubuntu in multiple computers. https://askubuntu.com/q/48535/124466

Comment: You want to sync the software from an EOL 2017 release with a current release? I can not see how that is going to work.